# Implementing IHttpSecurity in .NET (managed code)

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

How can I implement IHttpSecurity for Webbrowser Control in .NET?

I couldn't find any examples, all examples are in C++, also MSDN documentation is only for C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to use COM interop for this.  Look for the IID (guid) of the interface in the IDL file (urlmon.idl) and then recreate the interface in code.  You are probably going to have to attach the PreserveSig attribute to the OnSecurityProblem interface so that you can return the appropriate error code.